# Return the manager's name instead of the manager's userId

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to return the manager's name instead of the manager's userId.

```
SELECT u.fname, 
        u.lname,
        ua.email,
        (
            SELECT distinct u.mgrUserid
            FROM users
            WHERE u.mgrUserid IS NOT NULL
        ) AS 'manager'
FROM dbo.quizzes_users qu
INNER JOIN dbo.quizzes q ON qu.quizId = q.quizId
INNER JOIN dbo.users u ON qu.userId = u.userId
INNER JOIN intela.dbo.users_all ua ON u.userId = ua.userId
WHERE qu.quizId = @quizId
```

The above query currently gives me the following results:

```
fname       lname           email                         manager 
John        Smith           john.smith@email.com          5 
Tim         Walker          tim.walker@email.com          1
```

I'm trying to get the following results:

```
fname       lname           email                         manager
John        Smith           john.smith@email.com          Mike Jones
Tim         Walker          tim.walker@email.com          David Larson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
    (SELECT um.lname
     FROM users um
     WHERE u.mgrUserid = um.Userid
    ) AS manager
```

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN is an option

```
SELECT u.fname, 
        u.lname,
        ua.email,
        mgr.[manager's name] AS 'manager'
FROM dbo.quizzes_users qu
INNER JOIN dbo.quizzes q ON qu.quizId = q.quizId
INNER JOIN dbo.users u ON qu.userId = u.userId
INNER JOIN dbo.users mgr ON u.mgrUserId = mgr.UserId
INNER JOIN intela.dbo.users_all ua ON u.userId = ua.userId
WHERE qu.quizId = @quizId
```